# How to get an alert message when changing the options in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an ADD button which allows me to add some objects to the option that I selected in the dropdown. And I also have a function attached to that Add Button.

```
 onAddClicked = () =>{
        this.setState({
            showOptions: true
        }); 
       
    }


    <button type="button" onClick={this.onAddClick}
   style={{ float: "right",  marginLeft: "10px", marginRight: "10px" }}
    id="AddSelectedTag"
    className={((this.state.selectedOptions ?this.state.selectedOptions.length === 0 : true) ? 
    "re-btn-primary-inactive" : "re-btn-primary-blue")}disabled={(this.state.selectedOptions ? 
    this.state.selectedOptions.length === 0 : true) ? true : false}>Add 
    </button>
```

I can select and option and few objects under it. Now I need to display an error message when I want to change my option after selecting few objects under that. I am having state for my selected options as "this.state.selectedOptions".
I am trying

```
if(this.state.selectedOptions ? this.state.selectedOptions.value : null)
        {
          alert("selectedOptions value has changed");
        }
```

But this is returning an alert message everytime I click on the Add button, not when I try to change the state.

```
onViewAllTagClick = (event) => {
this.setState({
            showTagsSysController: true,
            selectedOptions: event,
        });
}


<li id="viewAllTags" className="re-exp-pak-edit-system-li">
 <div className="re-lbl-normal-12">
 <Select id="selectTags"
  styles={ddlUtils.getSnapDdlStyle(200)}
placeholder="Select Tag, Network or Hardware "
options={[{label:"Tag",value:2,isChild:0},
         {label:"Network",value:5,isChild:0},
         label:"Hardware",value:3,isChild:0},
                                            ]}
 value = { this.state.selectedOptions}
 isSearchable={false}
 isDisabled={this.state.isEdit === true}
 noOptionsMessage={() => null}
 onChange = {this.state.selectedSystems !== null ? this.onViewAllTagClick : null}>
</Select>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display a message if the user tries to change their selection after clicking the add button?

Comment: Yes I want the message to be displayed when the user tries to change the state of an option.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener like [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and compare props

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.selectedOptions !== prevProps.selectedOptions)
    alert("selectedOptions value has changed");
}
```

Comment: I am setting the the state of my selectedOptions using "this.state.selectedOptions", so when I try to change my state from one option to another after adding few objects in the Option I selected I should get that Alert message.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share more of your component code and where you are setting the state for selectedOptions.

Comment: I am sharing it in the question, can u plz check it there!

Comment: I have updated my question can u plz check it